# How to convert the Rust Mongo driver's BSON type to ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, rust

I'm working on a tool to sync a collection of Mongo documents to a Postgres database:

```
extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;
use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;

extern crate docopt;
use docopt::Docopt;

extern crate postgres;
use postgres::{Connection, SslMode};

static USAGE : &'static str = "
USAGE: user_importer  --mongo-url <mongo_url> --pg-url <pg_url>
       user_importer (--help)

Options:
  --mongo-url  Mongo Connection URI to the DB that has to users to be imported
  --pg-url   Postgres Connection URI to mizuna's DB
  -h, --help        Show this message
";

fn main() {
  let argv = std::env::args();
  let args = Docopt::new(USAGE).and_then(|d| d.argv(argv).parse()).unwrap_or_else(|e| e.exit());

  let mongo_url = args.get_str("<mongo_url>");
  let pg_url = args.get_str("<pg_url>");

  let pg = Connection::connect(pg_url, SslMode::None).unwrap();
  let stmt = pg.prepare("INSERT INTO mongo_users (mongo_id, email, name, sfdc_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)").unwrap();

  let mongo = Client::with_uri(mongo_url)
             .ok().expect("Failed to initialize client.");
  let coll = mongo.db("napa").collection("users");
  let cursor = coll.find(None, None).unwrap();

  for result in cursor {
    if let Ok(item) = result {
      println!("{:?}", item.get("_id").unwrap());
      println!("to_string {:?}", item.get("_id").unwrap().to_string());
      println!("to_json {:?}", item.get("_id").unwrap().to_json());
      let mongo_id  = item.get("_id").unwrap().to_string();
      let email     = item.get("email").map(|s| s.to_string());
      let name      = item.get("name").map(|s| s.to_string());
      let sfdc_id   = item.get("sfdc_id").map(|s| s.to_string());


      stmt.execute(&[&mongo_id, &email, &name, &sfdc_id]).unwrap();
    }
  }
}
```

([Playground](http://is.gd/QYzkBD))

The part I'm having trouble with is converting the document's `_id` field to a hex string (Line 43). It seems that `item.get("_id")` returns an object of type `BSON`, which has a few converters: `to_string()` returns `ObjectId("566740710ed3bc0a8f000001")`, and `to_json()` returns `{"$oid": "566740710ed3bc0a8f000001"}`, neither of which are the plan hex string that I want to insert. I see in the docs that `ObjectId` has a `to_hex()` function, but I can't figure out how to get from the `get()` method's `BSON` return type to the underlying `ObjectId` type that has that method implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`OrderedDocument::get_object_id()`](https://github.com/zonyitoo/bson-rs/blob/d5c12b07bdda945d49c74b4eaa9aa3774be48daa/src/ordered.rs#L283) method:

```
let mongo_id = item.get_object_id("_id").unwrap();
let mongo_id_hex = mongo_id.to_hex();
```

It is sad that bson-rs does not have any docs published anywhere.

Comment: Both answers are correct, but this one is simpler. I agree, it would have been nice if that `get_object_id` had been documented or used in an example anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: The reason there's no documentation is because `OrderedDocument` is in a private module (`ordered`), but there's a public type alias `Document` in a public module (`bson`) so you can still use the type.

Comment: @FrancisGagné the reason that there is no documentation is that it is not published anywhere :) `OrderedDocument` has doc comments, and they would be visible on `bson::Document` doc page, it's just you can't find it online.

Comment: I found documentation from the [mongo-rust-driver-prototype project](http://mongodb-labs.github.io/mongo-rust-driver-prototype/bson/type.Document.html), but that's only because rustdoc generates documentation for dependencies by default... And you can see from this link that the documentation for `OrderedDocument` is not available (perhaps if it had been a `pub use` instead of a `type`, it would have been).

Comment: @FrancisGagné, wow, indeed, I didn't get that it is just a type alias. In fact, I'm surprised that a type alias may point to private type, I'd personally consider it a bug in Rust.

Answer (score 2):

The `get()` methods returns an `Option<&Bson>`. [`Bson`](http://mongodb-labs.github.io/mongo-rust-driver-prototype/bson/enum.Bson.html) is an `enum`, so in order to access the data in a variant, you need to use pattern matching with `match` or `if let`.

```
let mongo_id  =
  match *item.get("_id").unwrap() {
    Bson::ObjectId(oid) => oid,
    _ => panic!("_id is not an ObjectId!"),
  };
```

This initializes `mongo_id` with the [`ObjectId`](http://mongodb-labs.github.io/mongo-rust-driver-prototype/bson/oid/struct.ObjectId.html) value for the `_id` field.

Answer (score 0):

With serde data model example.

```
let id: ObjectId = customer.id.unwrap();
let str_id: String = id.to_hex();
```

One line.

```
let str_id = customer.id.unwrap().to_hex();
```

The model example definition:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Customer {
    #[serde(rename = "_id", skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub id: Option<ObjectId>,
    pub name: String,
    ...
}
```