# generate ObjectId in rust mongo

Tags: mongodb, rust

i'm trying to convert String _id to a ObjectId object, what i'm already try :

```
 use mongodb::{Bson, bson, doc};
 Bson::ObjectId(str) // failed to resolve
 bson::Bson::String // undeclared /& private
```

library : [mongo-rust-driver-prototype](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-rust-driver-prototype)

Answer (score 4):

using `mongodb 2.2`

```
use std::str::FromStr;
...
let id = mongodb::bson::oid::ObjectId::from_str("id_str").unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
let mongo_id = str.get_object_id("_id").unwrap();
let mongo_id_hex = mongo_id.to_hex();
```

For more info please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070853/how-to-convert-the-rust-mongo-drivers-bson-type-to-objectid)

Comment: is `mongodb::oid::ObjectId::with_string(&"").unwrap()` works too ?

Comment: @RejoLojey Sorry I don't know much in `rust`. I just help to by giving relevant links which may help you. I just suggest to try and error.

Comment: @RejoLojey Please check link, It may clear your queries.

Comment: @RejoLojey welcome, You may accept the answer or give upvote. It will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generate ObjectId Object from string :

```
mongodb::oid::ObjectId::with_string(&"").unwrap() // change &"" with var or static value
```

References :

1. https://docs.rs/mongodb/0.3.12/mongodb/?search=object
2. https://docs.rs/mongodb/0.3.12/mongodb/oid/struct.ObjectId.html#method.with_string